# How do I detect clicks on links

Tags: javascript

I want to detect clicks on any link on a page so that I can trigger an ajax request to save the click (along with the URL) for analytics purposes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off if you're able to, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

You can then simply hook into each anchor:

```
$('a').click(function(){ /* Trigger ajax call here */});
```

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery:

```
document.body.onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if(target.nodeName === 'A') {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for being the one poster that didn't force JQuery on this guy

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery, try

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) { ... your stuff here ... });
```

docs here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work

```
$(function() {
    $(".detectClick").click(function() {          
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://example.com/path-to-your-ajax-request"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As my homonym said above, you should check jQuery.
Here for instance : http://api.jquery.com/click/